# Blackberry Messenger MDS error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to get the Blackberry Messenger SDKs to work on my machine.

I have installed the BBM MDS simulator and configured it to use the unlimited strength encryption. The MDS simulator starts just fine, and I can access internet on my simulators. However, I cannot get the two simulators to add each other as BBM Contacts. On the MDS window, I get an error message

`<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = GME, EVENT = Exception, EXCEPTIONCLASS = java,lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, CLASS = IncomingMessagesFromHigherLayer, METHOD = run, MESSAGE = net.rim.protocol.gme.compressionencryption.CENative.Compress<[B>[B>`

Anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had both the 64 bit version and the 32 bit version of the JDK installed on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. Uninstalling the 64 bit version of JDK solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set your system Language and Regional Settings to English.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you mean the computer settings or the simulator settings.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 (64 bit). Language is set to English(India) and location is India. Doesn't work. Tried with English(US) and location US, no luck. Any clues?